# Turing machine deciding $\{1^{2^n} : n \geq 0 \}$

Tags: turing-machines

How can I design a Turing machine that accepts the language $\{1^{2^n} : n \geq 0\}$?

Here is my attempt:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: This is a pretty easy homework question in undergraduate courses. What have you tried so far?

Comment: here i have tried [link](https://ibb.co/fv3mkd)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the idea:

> 1. Go over the entire input, crossing out every other 1 encountered.
> 2. Reject if the number of 1s encountered was odd but more than 1.
> 3. Accept if the number of 1s encountered was exactly 1.
> 4. Otherwise, go back to step 1.

Comment: thanks alot,i have done this,,but  i already tell that  i have confusion in designing turing machine?Can you design turing machine or modify my attempt turing machine?Thanks alot

Comment: Implementing the idea is akin to programming, which is off-topic here.

Comment: it's not programming,it's related to graphs,turing machines

Comment: What Yuval ment here was that you can do this yourself. He gave a high-level description of a suiting Turing machine. Implementing this one in an actual Turing machine with a list of transitions is not really hard from here. Just do the 4 steps state by state.